# How to generate this PBKDF2 with HMAC-SHA256 (.NET PasswordHasher<>)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, cryptojs

#### Question

According to online articles the .NET Core `PasswordHasher<>` class uses:

> ASP.NET Core Identity Version 3: PBKDF2 with HMAC-SHA256, 128-bit salt, 256-bit subkey, 10000 iterations

The [source code](https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore/blob/main/src/Identity/Extensions.Core/src/PasswordHasher.cs#L21) says this:

```
     /*
     * Version 2:
     * PBKDF2 with HMAC-SHA1, 128-bit salt, 256-bit subkey, 1000 iterations.
     * (See also: SDL crypto guidelines v5.1, Part III)
     * Format: { 0x00, salt, subkey }
     *
     * Version 3:
     * PBKDF2 with HMAC-SHA512, 128-bit salt, 256-bit subkey, 100000 iterations.
     * Format: { 0x01, prf (UInt32), iter count (UInt32), salt length (UInt32), salt, subkey }
     * (All UInt32s are stored big-endian.)
     */
```

What's the equivalent to hashing and validating a string with `PasswordHasher<>` V3 in Node?

#### What have I tried

Since `crypto` doesn't seem to support "PBKDF2 with HMAC-SHA256" I'm currently trying `pbkdf2-hmac` like this:

```
const generatedHash = arrayBufferToBase64(
    await pbkdf2Hmac(password, salt, 100000, 32, "SHA-256")
);
```

The thing I'm least certain about is the fourth argument (32) as on one hand .NET says "256-bit subkey" and on the other `pbkdf2Hmac` says that the fourth argument should be "intended length in octets of the derived key"; my reasoning was `256 / 8 = 32` but that's a wild guess.

In any case I've tried `32`, `64` and `256` for that value, I've also tried all combinations of SHA1, SHA256, SHA512 with 1000, 10000, 100000 iterations and nothing gives me the same `base64` string as `PasswordHasher<>`.

What am I missing?

#### Sample password

Given the password `sample123 !` the hash generated by `PasswordHasher<>` is:

```
AQAAAAEAACcQAAAAEAdmj6YuRrVMYBXbeGrV/j3VqSzvhIhE/xYWA0S1hpfxH5FuepoGJjite6n/Fh4quw==
```

Notice that if I read the implementation correctly then the salt is randomly generated and embedded in the hash.

Comment: Can you post a sample hash generated with `PasswordHasher<>`, including sample password?

Comment: What do you mean by *the same*? Hashed passwords contain a random salt which makes no two hashes same. Did you mean *nothing gives me the string that validates against the `PasswordHasher`*?

Comment: @WiktorZychla Yeah. The actual use case is that I have a bunch passwords in the database that were hashed with `PasswordHasher<>` and I need to generate the same hashes as `PasswordHasher<>` as well as validate them.

Comment: @Topaco Added the sample password

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For validation, the *subkey* must be calculated using PBKDF2 and compared with the *subkey* in the hash.

All information needed to calculate the key using PBKDF2 is contained in the hash:

- the digest used (*prf*)
- iteration count (*iter*)
- *salt length* and *salt*
  *subkey* in the hash is located at the end of the hash and has a length of 256 bits = 32 bytes.

This allows the key to be derived using PBKDF2 if the password is known:

```js
var hashB64 = "AQAAAAEAACcQAAAAEAdmj6YuRrVMYBXbeGrV/j3VqSzvhIhE/xYWA0S1hpfxH5FuepoGJjite6n/Fh4quw=="
var password = "sample123 !";

// Get digest, salt and iteration count:
// Format: { 0x01, prf (UInt32), iter count (UInt32), salt length (UInt32), salt, subkey }
var hash = Buffer.from(hashB64, "base64");
var marker = hash.subarray(0,1); // 0: V2, 1: V3
var prf = hash.readUInt32BE(1); // 0: HMAC/SHA1, 1: HMAC/SHA256, 2: HMAC/SHA512
var iter = hash.readUInt32BE(1 + 4);
var saltLen = hash.readUInt32BE(1 + 2*4);
var salt = hash.subarray(1 + 3*4, 1 + 3*4 + saltLen);
var subkey = hash.subarray(1 + 3*4 + saltLen);

// Calculate subkey with pbkdf2
var keySize = 32;
var subkeyPbkdf2 = crypto.pbkdf2Sync(password, salt, iter, keySize, prf == 0 ? "sha1" : (prf == 1 ? "sha256" : "sha512"));

console.log(subkey.compare(subkeyPbkdf2)); // 0 = successfully validated
```

The posted sample hash uses SHA-256 as digest, an iteration count of 10000, and a salt length of 16 bytes.

---

A new hash can be determined by generating a random 16 bytes salt, calculating the subkey from it using PBKDF2, and contacting all data according to the above specification.

Example (using the above values):

```js
var marker = 1;
var prf = 1; 
var iter = 10000;
var saltLen = 16;
var salt = "B2aPpi5GtUxgFdt4atX+PQ=="; // random salt
var subkey = "1aks74SIRP8WFgNEtYaX8R+RbnqaBiY4rXup/xYeKrs="; // via PBKDF2
var markerBuf = Buffer.allocUnsafe(1);
markerBuf.writeUInt8(marker);
var prfBuf = Buffer.allocUnsafe(4);
prfBuf.writeUInt32BE(prf);
var iterBuf = Buffer.allocUnsafe(4);
iterBuf.writeUInt32BE(iter);
var saltLenBuf = Buffer.allocUnsafe(4);
saltLenBuf.writeUInt32BE(saltLen);
var saltBuf = Buffer.from(salt, "base64");
var subkeyBuf = Buffer.from(subkey, "base64");
var hashPbkdf2 = Buffer.concat([markerBuf, prfBuf, iterBuf, saltLenBuf, saltBuf, subkeyBuf]);

var hashB64 = "AQAAAAEAACcQAAAAEAdmj6YuRrVMYBXbeGrV/j3VqSzvhIhE/xYWA0S1hpfxH5FuepoGJjite6n/Fh4quw==";
console.log(hashB64 === hashPbkdf2.toString("base64")); // true
```